# How to check whether all elements of a nested list are a subset of another list in R

Tags: r, if-statement, nested-lists

I've tried a number of different methods for this including [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410050/identify-which-objects-of-list-are-contained-subset-of-in-another-list-in-r) but nothing is working quite correctly.

My dataframe "SiteVisits" (a small subset dput is at bottom) is made up of columns `Date`(class = date), `TagID` (class = numeric), `SiteVisits` (a list of character), and `NumSites` (class = numeric).  Each row lists all sites where an individual organism (`TagID`) is found for each Date.

I'd like to assign whether a tag spent the entire day "inside", "outside", or "transiting" based on the sites it visited.  It can only be "inside" if it never visits an outside site, and it can only be "outside" if it never visits an inside site

First, 
I'd like to determine whether ALL the sites for a TagID for a Date are included in this list:

```
inside <- list(c("Release","IC1", "IC2", "IC3","RGD1"))
```

If TRUE `SiteVisit$Location = "INSIDE"`
ELSE test whether ALL sites for a TagID for a Date are contained within this list:

```
outside <- list(c("ORS1","WC1","WC2","WC3","RGU1","ORN1","ORN2","ORS3","GL1","CVP1","CLRS"))
```

If TRUE `SiteVisit$Location = "OUTSIDE"`
ELSE `SiteVisit$Location = "TRANSITING"`

I've tried a number of different `dplyr` and `base` versions to accomplish this, but none seem to get it right.  I think it's because I'm not correctly checking through each element of `SiteVisit$SiteVisits`

My current attempts are:

```
SiteVisit <- SiteVisit %>%
  mutate(Location = ifelse(all(SiteVisits[[]] %in% inside), "INSIDE",
                           ifelse(all(SiteVisits[[]] %in% outside),"OUTSIDE","TRANSITING")))
```

which yields all "INSIDE"

and

```
SiteVisit <- SiteVisit %>%
  mutate(Location = ifelse(all(SiteVisits[] %in% inside), "INSIDE",
                           ifelse(all(SiteVisits[] %in% outside),"OUTSIDE","TRANSITING")))
```

which yields all "TRANSITING"

also, attempting to do this in a for loop doesn't quite work

```
for (i in 1: nrow(SiteVisit)) {SiteVisit$Inside <- 
all(SiteVisit$SiteVisits[[i]] %in% inside)}
```

yields all FALSE while

```
all(SiteVisit$SiteVisits[[2]] %in% inside)
```

is TRUE

Here's a small subset of my dataframe "SiteVisit" dput:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15828, 15828, 15847, 15847, 
15847, 15847, 15847, 15847, 15848, 15848, 15848, 15848, 15848, 
15848, 15848, 15848, 15849, 15849, 15849, 15849, 15849, 15849, 
15849, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15851, 
15851, 15851, 15851, 15851, 15851, 15851, 15851, 15852, 15852, 
15852, 15852, 15852, 15852, 15852, 15853, 15853, 15853, 15853, 
15853, 15853, 15853, 15853, 15853, 15854, 15854, 15854, 15854, 
15854, 15854, 15854, 15854, 15855, 15855, 15855, 15855, 15855, 
15855, 15855, 15855, 15855, 15855, 15855, 15855, 15855, 15855, 
15856, 15856, 15856, 15856, 15856, 15856, 15856, 15856, 15856, 
15856, 15856, 15856, 15856, 15857, 15857, 15857, 15857, 15857, 
15857, 15857, 15857, 15857, 15857, 15857), class = "Date"), TagID = c(5717.06, 
6277.06, 5073.06, 5717.06, 11121.1, 11191.1, 11387.1, 11415.1, 
5717.06, 6277.06, 11121.1, 11191.1, 11219.1, 11289.1, 11387.1, 
11415.1, 5717.06, 11121.1, 11191.1, 11219.1, 11289.1, 11387.1, 
11415.1, 5717.06, 11121.1, 11191.1, 11219.1, 11289.1, 11387.1, 
11415.1, 5717.06, 11121.1, 11191.1, 11219.1, 11289.1, 11317.1, 
11387.1, 11415.1, 5717.06, 6277.06, 11191.1, 11219.1, 11289.1, 
11387.1, 11415.1, 5717.06, 6277.06, 9015.01, 9833.06, 11191.1, 
11219.1, 11289.1, 11387.1, 11415.1, 5717.06, 6277.06, 9015.01, 
11191.1, 11219.1, 11289.1, 11387.1, 11415.1, 5641.22, 5717.06, 
6221.06, 6277.06, 7909.22, 9015.01, 9833.06, 11121.1, 11191.1, 
11219.1, 11289.1, 11317.1, 11387.1, 11415.1, 5717.06, 6277.06, 
6529.06, 8119.01, 8545.06, 9015.01, 9497.06, 9833.06, 11191.1, 
11219.1, 11289.1, 11387.1, 11415.1, 5717.06, 6277.06, 6529.06, 
9015.01, 9497.06, 9833.06, 11191.1, 11219.1, 11289.1, 11387.1, 
11415.1), SiteVisits = list("Release", "Release", c("IC2", "IC1", 
"Release"), "IC3", "WC2", "RGD1", c("WC1", "WC3"), "WC3", "IC3", 
    "IC3", "WC2", "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "WC1", "WC3", "IC3", 
    "WC2", "RGD1", c("IC2", "IC1"), "IC1", "WC1", "WC3", "IC3", 
    "WC2", "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "WC1", "WC3", "IC3", "WC2", 
    "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "WC1", "WC1", "WC3", "IC3", "IC3", 
    "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "WC1", "WC3", "IC3", "IC3", c("IC3", 
    "Release"), c("IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "Release"), "RGD1", "IC2", 
    "IC1", "WC1", "WC3", "IC3", "IC3", c("IC3", "IC2"), "RGD1", 
    "IC2", "IC1", "WC1", "WC3", "Release", "IC3", "Release", 
    "IC3", c("RGD1", "Release"), c("IC3", "IC2"), c("IC3", "IC1"
    ), "WC2", "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "WC1", "WC1", "WC3", "IC3", 
    "IC3", c("RGD1", "Release"), c("RGD1", "Release"), "Release", 
    c("IC3", "IC2", "IC1"), "Release", c("IC3", "IC2", "IC1", 
    "RGD1"), "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "WC1", "WC3", "IC3", "IC3", 
    "RGD1", c("IC3", "IC2", "IC1"), "RGD1", c("IC3", "IC1", "RGD1"
    ), "RGD1", "IC2", c("IC2", "IC1"), "WC1", "WC3"), NumSites = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(15828, 15847, 15848, 15849, 15850, 15851, 
    15852, 15853, 15854, 15855, 15856, 15857), class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:2, 3:8, 9:16, 17:23, 24:30, 31:38, 39:45, 
        46:54, 55:62, 63:76, 77:89, 90:100)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works once `inside` and `outside` are stored as an `array` and not a `list`

```
inside <- c("Release", "IC1", "IC2", "IC3", "RGD1")
outside <- c("ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "RGU1", "ORN1", "ORN2", "ORS3", "GL1", "CVP1", "CLRS")

df1$Location <- lapply(df1$SiteVisits, function(x) ifelse(all(x %in% inside), "INSIDE", ifelse(all(x %in% outside), "OUTSIDE", "TRANSIT")))
```

Comment: That works, can you explain why that works?  I don't think I'm understanding why we can use lapply on vector (df1$SiteVisits)

Comment: `lapply` applies a function over a list or vector but will return a list.  But the reason why what you tried didn't work is because `%in%` was not looking at the array as it was nested in a list.  Changing the above to `%in% unlist(inside)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Want an answer that's about 1/100th as fast? (Not a typo*, this is way worse than manotheshark's answer, but it works on your data structured as it was).
*it was a typo! 1/100th not 1/10th

```
for (i in 1:nrow(SiteVisit)) {
  SiteVisit_test$Location[i] <- if (all(unlist(SiteVisit[i, ]$SiteVisits) %in% unlist(inside))) {
    "INSIDE"
  } else if (all(unlist(SiteVisit[i, ]$SiteVisits) %in% unlist(outside))) {
    "OUTSIDE"
  } else {"TRANSITIONING"}
}
```

Benchmarks for the 2 approaches:

```
microbenchmark(
  for_statement = for (i in 1:nrow(SiteVisit)) {
    SiteVisit_test$Location[i] <- if (all(unlist(SiteVisit[i, ]$SiteVisits) %in% unlist(inside))) {
      "INSIDE"
    } else if (all(unlist(SiteVisit[i, ]$SiteVisits) %in% unlist(outside))) {
      "OUTSIDE"
    } else {"TRANSITIONING"}
  },
  lapply_statemnt = lapply(SiteVisit$SiteVisits, function(x) ifelse(all(x %in% inside2), "INSIDE", ifelse(all(x %in% outside2), "OUTSIDE", "TRANSIT")))
)

Unit: microseconds
            expr     min      lq      mean  median       uq     max neval
   for_statement 28874.4 30082.0 32411.968 31008.3 33108.90 48878.1   100
 lapply_statemnt   268.4   284.2   346.201   295.5   310.85  4114.9   100
```

I don't really get why the lapply approach is so much faster here... probably because I'm unlisting for every i in the loop.